# C# Static public fields for increment thread actors execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, thread-safety, akka.net

I'm building a system using AKKA.net (maybe irrelevant for this problem) and I have a class which is responsible for count he number of actors running (for who that does not know actors they can be seem as threads for simplify). So basically I have a static public field:

```
class MyClass{
    public static long TotalOutstandingRequests;
}
```

and I increment/decrement it inside the actors/threads (because I have actores which start/run others actores) with:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref MyClass.TotalOutstandingRequests);
Interlocked.Decrement(ref MyClass.TotalOutstandingRequests);
```

what happen is that the IDE and internet says that is a bad idea to have a  public static field, so I would like to know if there is an alternative for my problem, or not if is totally OK let the things the way it are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use it properly, it is not **such** a bad idea.

Anyway, you can expose some static methods, like:

```
public static long AddRequest() 
{
    return Interlocked.Increment (ref _totalOutstandingRequests);
}

public static long RemoveRequest() 
{
    return Interlocked.Decrement (ref _totalOutstandingRequests);
}

public static long GetRequests() 
{
    return _totalOutstandingRequests;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bad idea is because it can be become non-static overtime (while you developing).

Why you ask? Simply because at some point of time you will want non-static dependency in this static one. Be it logger, database, helper class, service, connection, whatever have different lifetime.

With non-static on the other hand, you can easly make it **static by ensuring you create it once** or use dependency injection to easly manage **singletons** and other possible lifetimes (yes, there is multiple lifetimes, such as **per-connection, per-session, per-thread**, etc).

So as to solution:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public long TotalOutstandingRequests;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    //some incrementing, decrementing code here
    public MyClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public void AddRequest()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref TotalOutstandingRequests);
        _logger.Debug("New request here!");
    }
}
```

So when to use static? Simple:

- when you are sure it has no dependencies, will not have in future and be craved into stone (language extensions, such as LINQ, Regex, any helper methods, constants, etc)
- you working with unmanaged code (invoking windows functions, etc).

I have never met code, which can't live without static except these two cases.

**PS**

If it is home project - you can forget about what I said and just do it the way you want =)